# How to merge png files using Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-processing, gd

I have two png files(with transparent background), I wana merge them and create one image using Codeigniter(I didn't find anything related in image userguide of Codeigniter).

How it's possible?

Comment: Do you mean jQuery or Codeigniter? You appear to have changed your mind between typing the title of the question and the body of it.

Comment: Sorry about the mistake! it's edited now.. yes I wana make it happen using codeigniter or php functions in Codeigniter. how it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the 2 images by using the PHP function [imagecopymerge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php)

```
<?php
$src1 = imagecreatefrompng('image1.png');
$src2 = imagecreatefrompng('image2.png');

//Change the arguments below to suit your needs
imagecopymerge($src1, $src2, 50, 50, 50, 50, 200, 200, 100); 

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($src1);

imagedestroy($src1);
imagedestroy($src2);
?>
```